# how to remove class in ul nested li

Tags: html, css, class, nested, html-lists

I have a problem in nested ul list.
I want to remove the class "per-esempio" from the second nested ul.

```
<ul class="per-esempio blue">
   <li>
      <ul id="nested-ul">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

---

Here the result:
https://jsfiddle.net/m75Lknrw/

```
<ul class="per-esempio blue">
   <li>qewrqwerqwerqwerqwerwqre
      <ul id="nested-ul">
        <li>adfasdfasdfasdf</li>
        <li>asdfasdfasdfasdf</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't want to show blue triangle in nested ul list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must declare which language you are working with, what you have tried so far and why that did not work.

Comment: I have posted a jsfiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul.per-esempio li:before { content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 11 10" height="10" width="11"> <path style="stroke-width:0" fill="rgba(0, 100, 176, 0.99)" d="M 10,4.5 0.04495414,9 H 0 V 0 0 Z"/></svg> '); padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 10px; }
```

Remove that class selector from your CSS and the blue arrows will go away. There ya go help that helps.

Comment: Thanks Brent, but I want to remove only the blue arrow in ul nested, not the first arrow.